# Passport facebook logout not working

Tags: node.js, facebook, passwords

I trying to implement passport Facebook the code i have in server.js is shown below
route which is used when user click login via facebook

```
 router.get('/auth/facebook',
      passport.authenticate('facebook',{ scope : 'email' }),
      function(req, res){
      });
```

on successful login it redirects to success.html which as the logout button

```
 router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/success',
        failureRedirect: '/'
      }),
      function(req, res) {
        res.render('success.html');
      });
```

logout route is

```
  router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/');
    });
```

if i click on logout button still i will be redirected to home page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('auth.html');
});
```

auth.html

```
  <html>
        <head>
          <title>Node.js OAuth</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="/auth/facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>
        </body>
        </html>




but after if i click the Sign in with Facebook link i will directly take to success.html page  and again i was never able to see the Facebook login page where we provide the credentials of the Facebook account
```

*i tried remove the details from the database but still it is pointing to to success.html
*i tried by removing the cookie as well as with new instance of browser
*no luck please point me to filed what might be the error

Answer (score 1):

Your page is redirected to 'success.html' because Facebook remembers the login credentials. Unless you manually logout from Facebook, your app will always be redirected to 'success.html'.

This is what you could do to log out of Facebook from your app.

In your logout.html page:

```html
<form action="/logoutFromFacebook" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="accessToken" value="<%= user.accessToken %>"/>
</form>
```

Following code goes into your controller:

```js
router.post('/logoutFromFacebook', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next='+server.ip+'/logout&access_token='+req.body['accessToken']);
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

server.ip needs to be the url where your app is running from.
Eg: http://localhost:3000 if it is running locally
OR
http://128.800.90.67:3000 if it is running remotely

Answer (score 0):

See [passport-facebook's documentation for re-authentication](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#re-authentication).

Change the first bit to look something like this:

```
router.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: 'email',
    authType: 'reauthenticate',
    authNonce: 'foo123'
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the facebook token which is associated to the user

```
const url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me/permissions?access_token="+accesstoken;
     firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.delete(url).pipe(
        catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
          throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.response);
        }),
      ),
    );
```